# ¿Como convertir selección de un array a String JAVA?

Tags: java, mysql, array, string

La situación es la siguiente, tengo un JOptionPane que dentro tiene un combobox, ese combobox esta lleno de datos de una columna dentro de una tabla en una base de datos, el código es el siguiente:

```
 //Tomemos en cuenta que en otra clase tengo una función que retorna una conexión a una base de datos
  Connection con =Db.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prueba1", "root", "1234");//Conectarse a la base de datos
   String SSQL = "SELECT * FROM conect";//condición sql la tabla donde esta mi resultado se llama conect
  ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();//lista donde almacenamos nuestros resultados
 
 //hacemos la busqueda dentro de la base de datos
 PreparedStatement st = null;
 try {
     st = con.prepareStatement(SSQL);
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(PortalJuridico.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
    ResultSet rs = null;
 try {
     rs = st.executeQuery();
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(PortalJuridico.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }

 try {
    
     while (rs.next()){
         
       list.add(rs.getString("nombre"));//añadimos a la lista todos los resultados de la columna "Nombre"
     }
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(PortalJuridico.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
    String[] result = new String[list.size()];//declaramos result como string
    result = list.toArray(result);//añadimos nuestra lista a result
    Object opcion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Selecciona una opción", "Elegir",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,result, result[3]);
    base = String.valueOf(result);
    System.out.println(base);
```

Mi idea es que cuando yo haga una selección de ese combobox, el valor de ese combobox se almacene en la variable base.
ejemplo, si en el combobox escojo: Inventarios, entonces base = inventarios;
para eso use lo siguiente:

```
   base = String.valueOf(result);
```

Ya que en result se almacenas los resultados de mi búsqueda, sin embargo al momento de imprimir me da resultados como:

```
 [Ljava.lang.String;@7385fa20
 [Ljava.lang.String;@74eef9db
 [Ljava.lang.String;@4861c19c
```

Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de recibir el string que corresponde en lugar de esos resultados, agradecería sus respuestas, adjunto imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el problema, y era mucho mas fácil de lo que parecía.

la cosa era que pase por alto el Object opción, el cual contenía el string seleccionado dentro de la lista.

```
  base = (String) opcion;
    System.out.println(base);
```

así quedaba.

Answer (score 0):

Para convertir un array en un String en Java puedes usar. **String.join()**:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join

Básicamente tienes que escribir:

```
base = String.join(",", list);
```

To conversion a arrays es innecesario.